# Android adb returns the "device not found" error

Tags: android, adb

When I plug my HTC Desire S phone into the PC (Win7) via USB, Device Manager shows a network adapter called "HTC Remote NDIS based Device".

Attempting a port mapping with adb, this happens:

```
7:22:09.68>"C:\Program Files\HTC\HTC Sync 3.0\adb" forward tcp:7777 tcp:7777
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
error: device not found
```

Do you have any advice?

Comment: check if usb tethering in enabled on your phone. disable it and try agian. to check if usb tethering is enabled goto settings>wireless&networks> here you can find option to Tethering. disable and try again.

Comment: I have the same issue with my Note 2 attached to windows 7. Windows sees it just fine, but adb does not. I've verified tethering is off (even tried with it on) and have toggled the debug on/off, killed server and restarted etc, but still nothing. I'll have to try a different device tomorrow just to make sure its not the phone.

Comment: @TobinRysenga did you ever solve it? please share

Answer (score 2):

Several responses mention "Select the "Unknown sources" checkbox; you find it in "Settings->Applications->Unknown sources."

Perhaps that was an option in a previous version of Android, but for me (using Android 4.4) there is no "Applications" sub-menu under "Settings".  This appears to have moved to:
"Settings" -> *Security* -> "Unknown sources"

Answer (score 1):

First check whether the device is attached or not with "adb devices" command (it is inside the platform-tools directory).

Just for information, to start with Android application development with a real device, you have to change some settings:

1. Select the "Unknown sources" checkbox; you find it in "Settings->Applications->Unknown sources."
2. Select the "USB Debugging" checkbox; you find it in "Settings->Applications->Development->USB Debugging."

Comment: The device is connected - the network connection is shown only when the connection is made. "adb devices" shows no devices. So it's connected, Windows can see it, but adb can't see it.

Comment: OK I can now see the device - turning USB debugging off then on on the device seems to have kicked it into life.

Comment: @SirHowy check my updated answer and make the settings same as i mentioned if you forgot or missed any.

Comment: I did what you said, but `adb devices -l ` still does not find my device. any other ideas?

Comment: what if running ./adb devices doesn't return/detect my genymotion emulator?

Comment: adb kill-server adb start-server tp restart the server didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

First check if the device is connected; type the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\HTC\HTC Sync 3.0\adb devices
```

If the device gets listed, then perform your task; otherwise, there is a problem with the connection.

Comment: This is a good tip. Led me to restarting my emulator, which then it showed up, when running this command.

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect you device in **Media Device (MTP)** mode.

I have the same problem and after switching to **MTP** mode `adb` was found my device.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reboot your phone ? That worked for me once

Answer (score 0):

try installing your correct driver,I got mine on https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481

Answer (score 0):

enable USB Tethering. The device would be listed via `adb devices` (workes for my LG G2/Lollipop)

Comment: i ebabled usb tethering, and still `adb devices -l` returns an empty list of devices. ideas?