# Error when installing apk on the emulator: Device not found

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android dab returns the “device not found” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441248/android-dab-returns-the-device-not-found-error)

I'm installing an `apk` file on the android emulator. My `ADB` is in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

When I use `adb intall <apk file name>`  then it shows:

```
Error: device not found
```

Comment: before, install apk file start emulator?

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of that, only slightly related

Answer (score 1):

First check to see if the device is connected to adb using adb devices, if it isnt there restart the AVD